# Why I cannot export a report to word in SSRS 2014?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have an SSRS 2014 and have multiple application reports on that.
For the report_A, I can export (save) the result as XML, CSV, PDF, MHTML, Excel, TIFF file, and Word.
But for the report_B, I only can export (save) the result as CSV, and PDF.
Let's take Word for example.
I checked rsreportserver.config on this server and found:

```
    <Extension Name="WORD" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.WordRenderer.WordDocumentRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.WordRendering" Visible="false"/>
    <Extension Name="WORDOPENXML" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.WordRenderer.WordOpenXmlRenderer.WordOpenXmlDocumentRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.WordRendering"/>
```

If I change Visible="false" to Visible="true" in the 1st row. I can export report_B as CSV, PDF, and Word.
Why some reports invoke WORDOPENXML and some don't?

I checked the schema version of these reports and they are all 2010.

Anyone can explain this? and how to resolve it instead of modifying the config file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful or not but I think docx format (WORDOPENXML) is only supported from SSRS 2012 onwards. If your report schema is 2010, that 'might' be the issue. Check the project properties and see what version of SSRS is targeted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some hard-coding on the application side and the DEV modified it and the issue is gone.

Thank you for your time on this.